# php: md5 different passwords encoded the same way

Tags: php, md5

I'm not a php programmer, so I only know what I have looked up online about the `md5` tag.

I am checking to see if passwords match in a php page.  I send the password in the php url and retrieve it with this code:

```
$u_pswd = md5(trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['pswd'])));
```

Then I run a query to get the user's password so I can check if they are the same:

```
$usql = "SELECT user_password FROM ft_users WHERE user_email = '".$u_mail."'";
$ures = mssql_query($usql);
$urow = mssql_fetch_array($ures);
if ($urow['user_password'] = $u_pswd) {
    // passwords match
} else {
    // passwords do not match
}
```

My problem is that it says the passwords match every time.  For example, if the current password is `PASSWORD` and I send it a password `INCORRECT`, the output is:

`$_pswd` = 64a4e8faed1a1aa0bf8bf0fc84938d25

`$urow['user_password']` = 64a4e8faed1a1aa0bf8bf0fc84938d25

Could someone help me out in solving why it is saying the passwords are the same when they are not?

Comment: are you sure that you fetch the correct data in $_REQUEST['pswd']

Comment: This is an incredibly insecure way of storing passwords (Google *"MD5 rainbow tables"*) - try `password_hash()` instead if you're running PHP 5.5+ :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use "=" for comparison. "=" will assign a value and any expression "$var = $value" will be evaluated to true. Use "==" instead.

```
if ($urow['user_password'] == $u_pswd) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

= is for assigning , in your code you are assigning  `$u_pswd` value to `$urow['user_password']`

you need to compare those values are equal or not by using == to get required result

```
$usql = "SELECT user_password FROM ft_users WHERE user_email = '".$u_mail."'";
$ures = mssql_query($usql);
$urow = mssql_fetch_array($ures);
if ($urow['user_password'] == $u_pswd) {

} 
else 
{

}
```

Hope it helps.